# ubuntu server 16.04.2 redmine problem

Tags: 16.04, server, redmine

Could anyone give me an advice what to do.
I'm trying to install redmine on ubuntu server 16.04.2.
I've followed the [manual](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step). I used postgres packages, so as redmine-pgsql. I installed gem and created succesfully redmine base in postgres, changed apache2 configuration files. 
When i now try to enter redmine by http:\\192.168.9.100\redmine it shows me redmine folder contents.
It seems like smthg bad happened to ruby or it's gem... How can i check what goes wrong? Could anyone help me with that guy?

Comment: Have you fixed your issue yet?

Comment: No, i've installed Bitnami's redmine installer and imported my past redmine's database.

Comment: I tried it and did not like Bitnami's stack...
I ended up using debian package "redmine"... apt install redmine #3.2.1-2